# XMPP, CoreData - how to load only self and destination user messages?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data, xmpp

I save to core data and load all messages with code below, but how can I load only messages for 2 users, for self user and for destination user, I want base it on user JID.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self appDelegate].xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *messageEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
fetchRequest.entity = messageEntity;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
//Now you get the NSArray with element type of "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your message objects have a `from` relationshit to a `User` entity.
As simple as adding (before executing the request):

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"from = %@ OR from = %@",selfUser,otherUser];
```

Where `selfUser` and `otherUser` are `User` core data managed objects or managed object IDs of  users.

if you use a field identifier (highly not recomended):

```
 fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bareJID.bare = %@ OR bareJID.bare = %@",selfUser.jid,otherUser.jid];
```

You might want to read [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1)

Comment: I use     fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bareJidStr = %@ OR bareJidStr = %@", self.sourceUser.uJid, self.destinationUser.uJid];
but I have still messages from all users

Comment: and in message entry I have not got from that user id it is

Comment: I add output in question body

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is wrong, and your output does not tell much nor does it use the predicate. You need to set the predicate before you execute the request.

Comment: May be problem is in from="168@kotikiwebcrew.com/ms-MacBook-Air" and in [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"from = %@ OR from = %@", ? Is it possible to take from field without detail info?

Comment: You could parse the string to remove the detail info (it won't work otherwise). The predicate You mentioned in your first comment should work as long as you are comparing valid values and your data in the store match the values you seek ...

Comment: Ok, is there way to choose with predicate message where sender and receiver is exact jid?

Comment: and how can I define sender of current message? I can see if it outputting or not, but if I change users - it will not work...there is not such parameter as sender in XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject

Comment: I GOT THIS! ,    Do your code:     fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bareJidStr = %@ OR bareJidStr = %@", self.sourceUser.uJid, self.destinationUser.uJid];
take message between  sourceUser and destinationUser?

Comment: My predicate will yeild ONLY messages of sourceUser and destinationUser (if you don't have garbage data in your store). This is the only way to get these messages witout creating the relationship I mentioned in the first option.

Comment: Both Methods doesnot work as it gives exceptions like there is no key from and barejid

Answer (score 1):

I have used following method and it worked correctly :)

```
-(void)checkForPastMessageAndDisplayIt
{
    NSString *strmyid = @"user1@domain";
    NSString *strBuddy = @"user2@domain";

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_message_achiving];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bareJidStr = %@ OR bareJidStr = %@", strmyid, strBuddy];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *messagesArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    [messagesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        id messageObject = [messagesArray objectAtIndex:idx];
        if ([messageObject isKindOfClass:[XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject class]]) {

            XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *currentMessageCoreDataObject = (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject*)messageObject;
            XMPPMessage *message = currentMessageCoreDataObject.message;
            if (message!=nil) {
                [messages addObject:message];
            }

        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that

```
-(void)testMessageArchiving {

    NSString *strmyid = @"myid";
    NSString *strBuddy ="toid";
    NSLog(@"my id and buddy is is %@ and %@",strmyid,strBuddy);

    XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bareJidStr = %@ OR bareJidStr = %@", strmyid, strBuddy];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // NSLog(@"the history of messages is %@",messages);

    [self print:[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:messages]];
```